# How to rewrite uri with location directive in nginx config

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have searched many articles and posts but didn't find any particular fix for my requirement. Hence, posting this question.

I have 2 locations on my server /p1 and /p2. The default location should be /p1/index.html.

I want, when I will access http://localhost:8080/p1 or http://localhost:8080/p2 then I should be able to get the data from http://localhost:8080/p1/index.html, and also the URL should change in the browser.

Can we use any other directives instead of location directives to achieve this?

Below is the current Nginx config :

```
server {

      listen      80;
      root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

      location / {
      try_files $uri /p1/index.html;
      }
      
      location /p1 {
      try_files $uri /p1/index.html;
      }      

      location /p2 {
      try_files $uri /p1/index.html;
      }
}
```

Need in this way :

```
http://localhost:8080/p1 -->  http://localhost:8080/p1/index.html
http://localhost:8080/p2 -->  http://localhost:8080/p1/index.html
```

Any suggestion or help will be grateful.

Comment: You mean `return 301 $scheme://$host/p1/index.html` ?

Comment: Maybe, let me try this. But, this $host:? , what should be used for port.

Comment: `$host` will be determined from the request.

Comment: @JDGuide There are too many uncertainties in your question. What do you want to do with the `/p1/` request? With the `/p10` request? With the `/p1/any/other/string` request? All the three will be processed with the `location /p1 { ... }` block. Saying _the URL should change in the browser_ you mean you need an HTTP redirect and not an internal redirect made by the `try_files` directive.

Comment: @IvanShatsky mine required uri was /p1 only,  not with any other strings.

Comment: @JDGuide Then you can use an exact match location. For HTTP 301 permanent redirect (cached by proxies and browsers) use `location = /p1 { return 301 /p1/index.html; } location = /p2 { return 301 /p1/index.html; }` or change return code to 302 for HTTP 302 temporary (non-cacheable) redirects.

Comment: Sure will try this once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some clue from @BijayRegmi's comment. I have modified little and the below changes worked for me.

```
server {

      listen      80;
      root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

      location / {
      try_files $uri /p1/index.html;
      }
      
      location /p1 {
      try_files $uri /p1/index.html;
      }      

      location /p2 {
      return 301 $scheme://$http_host/p1/index.html;
      }
}
```